# SQL Server request is very slow when nothing to retrieve?

Tags: performance, sql-server-express

We are facing a strange performance problem with "SQL Server Express 2005" in a very simple condition.

We have a table with: [timestamp], [id], [value] columns.
and only one primary unique index on [timestamp]+[id].

The table contains around 68.000.000 records.

The request is:
SELECT TOP 1 timestamp FROM table WHERE id=1234 ORDER BY timestamp

If there is at least one record for this id the result is given in few miliseconds.
If there is *no* record for this id the result is given in at least 30 SECONDS!!!

We tried many other simple similar request, and as soon as we have no corresponding records for the id the processing time is awfully long.

Do you have any explanation and idea to avoid this?

Comment: I suspect you'll need another index, maybe again id+timestamp or just id but including timestamp. What do you see for the query execution plan in Management Studio?

Comment: Please compare execution plans and post them. I suppose there is a difference there.

Comment: We are going to generate this index to give a try, thanks.

Comment: One more information: the execution plan show that "Clustered Index Seek" costs more than 96%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TOP 1 ORDER BY what?

If it finds one record, it must scan the entire table to find more, since you don't have
an index on id.

If you did, but wanted "ORDER BY timestamp", it would still table scan because it doesn't know  the id is unique in the timestamp index (even though it might make sense to you because the id is declared unique, say - is it? How if it's not a unique index of its own or as the 1st field in a multicolumn index? - or they both increase monotonically, say - do they?)

Comment: In fact the "ORDER BY timestamp" was in the original query, we just tried to remove it but the result is the same. This index is a unique index.

Comment: The solution is to add another index on "id", hoping this will not degrade to much insertion time since it is critical in this application.

Answer (score 0):

If the ID is a unique ID then your `ORDER BY` isn't needed - and an index on just that field would be enough.